# If steady current flows in a metallic conductor of non uniform cross section area then why is current constant?

Tags: electric-current

If area is not uniform then how can current be constant? What happens to current density, electric field, drift speed? Are they constant?

Comment: How would the current not be constant? Where would it disappear to and reappear from?

Comment: Ummmm yeah and what about the other things

Comment: Well, what about them? Assuming the total current remains constant, what happens?

Comment: Electric field and drift velocity should be same, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

If the current is steady, then the integral of current density on each cross section is constant. Therefore current density (and, through Ohm's law, electric field) will vary with cross section.

For an arbitrary shape you have to solve Laplace's equation to get the potential inside the conductor, setting mixed boundary conditions: fix potential on both ends, and fix a zero normal derivative on the side surface (so no current escapes). Taking the gradient of this potential gives you electric field and, through Ohm's law, current density.